# No Main Function

Tags: java, program-entry-point

ok, so I am trying to run this and it tells me there is no main (i have tried putting one in and i get a termination and syntax error) what is wrong and/or where do I put the main function?

here is the code

```
import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class StyleListener extends JPanel
{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private JCheckBox bold, italic;
private JLabel saying;
private JSplitPane splitPane;

public StyleListener()

 {  
   splitPane = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT);
   splitPane.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
   splitPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,200));
   splitPane.setBackground(Color.green);
   splitPane.setDividerLocation(100);

   JPanel subPanel1 = new JPanel();
   subPanel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
   subPanel1.setBackground(Color.cyan);
   saying = new JLabel ("Say it with style!");
   saying.setFont (new Font ("Helvetica", Font.PLAIN, 36));
   subPanel1.add (saying);
   splitPane.setTopComponent(subPanel1);

   JPanel subPanel2 = new JPanel();
   subPanel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
   subPanel2.setBackground(Color.green);
   bold = new JCheckBox ("Bold");
   bold.setToolTipText("Check this box to make text fatter.");
   bold.setBackground (Color.green);
   italic = new JCheckBox ("Italic");
   italic.setToolTipText("Check this box to make text slantier looking.");
   italic.setBackground (Color.green);
   subPanel2.add (bold);
   subPanel2.add (italic);
   splitPane.setBottomComponent(subPanel2);

   add(splitPane);

   StyleListener listener = new StyleListener();
   bold.addItemListener (listener);
   italic.addItemListener (listener);

   public void itemStateChanged (ItemEvent event)
   {
      int style = Font.PLAIN;

      if (bold.isSelected())
        style = Font.BOLD;

      if (italic.isSelected())
        style += Font.ITALIC;

      saying.setFont (new Font ("Helvetica", style, 36));
   }
```

Comment: Looks like some random file of some reasonably sized project - it is unlikely to get it alone to compile and run as complete application... Please consider asking original author of the code about what context this file should be used in...

Comment: Take a look at [A Closer Look at the "Hello World!" Application](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/index.html?utm_source=twitterfeed&utm_medium=twitter) - pay attention to the section on "The `main` Method"

Comment: Where _is_ the `main` you supposedly added? And where is the frame you add the panel class to?

Comment: ֲֲֲ@user3566865: Your code doesn't compile `The method addItemListener(ItemListener) in the type AbstractButton is not applicable for the arguments (StyleListener)`

Answer (score 0):

It's a Class file.. 
Before trying to copy classes you should make sure to have a main function..

Try the hello world project and add that Class file to your project..

Comment: i added a class, and it still says i have no main type